# Duplicate results when searching with explode in advanced search

Tags: php

I am doing advanced search based on title and here is my code. First I am searching based on whole title. If any of the books are not found I search based on each word present in title.

The problem is if two or more words match title in second case then it prints duplicate books.

```
$qry="select * from books where quantity>0 ";
if(isset($title)&&isset($submit1))
$qry.=" and title like '%".$title."%' ";
$books=mysqli_query($con,$qry);
      $numrows=mysqli_num_rows($books);

      if($numrows>0){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($books)){
           //print books
        }
      }
      else if(isset($submit1)&&isset($title)){
          $words=explode(" ",$title);
          $notfound=true;
          foreach($words as $value){
              $qry="select * from books where quantity>0 ";

              $qry.=" and title like '%".$value."%' ";
              $books=mysqli_query($con,$qry);
              $numrows=mysqli_num_rows($books);

              if($numrows>0){
                  while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($books)){
                       // print based on each word
                  }}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you do a separate query for the title and each word instead of using `or` ?

Comment: If the title is found then no need of checking each word. so I have done that

Comment: Alright, but why not use `or` in the query based on words ? You wouldn't get any duplicates.

Comment: No. It will then give all results of quantity>0

Comment: Use a global array for the scope of the code you're working in. Then add all results to that array from all different queries, as long as that item is not already in your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing a separate query for each word and dealing with duplicates after, you should change your SQL query to search for any of the words at once using `or`. Just don't forget the parentheses as you have another condition there.

Eventually you should end up with something more or less like this:

```
$words=explode(" ",$title);
$conditions = [];

foreach ($words as $word) {
    $conditions[] = "title like '%" . $word ."%'";
}

$query = sprintf(
    "select * from books where quantity > 0 and (%s)",
    join(" or ", $conditions)
);

$books = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$numrows = $mysqli_num_rows($books);

...
```

Comment: Got it. What is the best way 'or' on conditions or 'and' on conditions?

Comment: `$conditions` stores the `like` conditions for each word. If you want to search for titles containing any of the words, you should use `or` to join them, if you want to find titles containing all of the words, you should use `and`.